# Deriving Chern-Simons term from path integral representation of the first quantized non interacting many body Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

This is an exercise from condensed matter filed theory book of altland and simons.

**Exercise**

Subject the first quantized many particle hamiltonian $H=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{p^{i}{^{2}}}{2m}+V(x^i)$ to singular gauge transformation $\psi\rightarrow \psi\exp[-2is\sum_{i<j}\arg(x^i-x^j)]$. Then construct a path integral representation for the transition amplitude $\langle x|U(t)|y\rangle$. Show that decoupling of the nonlinear gauge field contribution acquired by the Hamiltonian exactly parallels the field integral scheme discussed above.(that discussion is just the derivation of chern simons terms). As before action contains the Chern simons contribution $-\int dx^3\epsilon_{\mu\nu\sigma} a_\mu\partial_\nu a_\sigma$ and a current vector potential coupling. The latter is given by $$\int dt \sum_i \phi(x^i)+\dot{x^i}a_i(x^i)$$

**Attempt**

Under the gauge transformation the path integral is $$\langle x|U(t)|y\rangle=\int D(x)D(p)\exp[\int
 dt\sum_{i=1}^{N}p^i\dot{x}^i-\frac{[p^{i}+a(x^i)]{^{2}}}{2m}-V(x^i)]\tag{1}$$ where $$a(x_i)=-2s\partial_{x^i}\sum_{i<j}\arg(x^i-x^j). \tag{2}$$

So How do i get the Chern simons and current potential coupling terms from eq (1).

Comment: Can you perhaps provide references to whatever set of lectures/textbook you're using?